# Dynamically populating the number of tables based on JSON input obtained - angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to populate number of tables dynamically by the input I get via JSON in angularJS.

I am perplexed on what to use and how to use since I am a learner in angular.

Would be helpful if anybody could help.

I have this JSON obtained in my script.

```
{
  "took": 167,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 22.126987,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "3423",
        "_score": 22.126987,
        "_source": {
          "mdmId": "45234",
          "fullName": "rick j cruz",
          "firstName": "rick",
          "middleName": "j",
          "lastName": "cruz",
          "gender": "MALE",
          "employeeInd": "N",
          "phoneList": [],
          "partyAdresses": [
            {
              "addressType": "home",
              "address1": "xxx",
              "address2": "yyy",
              "city": "SAN JOSE",
              "state": "CA",
              "zipCode": "zzz"
            },
            {
              "addressType": "mailing",
              "address1": "xxx",
              "address2": "yyy",
              "city": "SAN JOSE",
              "state": "CA",
              "zipCode": "zzz"
            }
          ],
          "policyList": [
            {
              "agencyCode": "50000",
              "agentid": "500",
              "sourceSystem": "unit",
              "policyNumber": "123",
              "policyNumberRaw": "123",
              "policyStatus": "CANCELLED",
              "roleList": [
                {
                  "roleType": "INSURED",
                  "roleStatus": "ACTIVE",
                },
                {
                  "roleType": "LISTED DRIVER",
                  "roleStatus": "ACTIVE",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "3423",
        "_score": 22.126987,
        "_source": {
          "mdmId": "45234",
          "fullName": "rick j cruz",
          "firstName": "rick",
          "middleName": "j",
          "lastName": "cruz",
          "gender": "MALE",
          "employeeInd": "N",
          "phoneList": [],
          "partyAdresses": [
            {
              "addressType": "home",
              "address1": "xxx",
              "address2": "yyy",
              "city": "SAN JOSE",
              "state": "CA",
              "zipCode": "zzz"
            },
            {
              "addressType": "mailing",
              "address1": "xxx",
              "address2": "yyy",
              "city": "SAN JOSE",
              "state": "CA",
              "zipCode": "zzz"
            }
          ],
          "policyList": [
            {
              "agencyCode": "50000",
              "agentid": "500",
              "sourceSystem": "unit",
              "policyNumber": "123",
              "policyNumberRaw": "123",
              "policyStatus": "CANCELLED",
              "roleList": [
                {
                  "roleType": "INSURED",
                  "roleStatus": "ACTIVE",
                },
                {
                  "roleType": "LISTED DRIVER",
                  "roleStatus": "ACTIVE",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I now need to populate two different tables based on the **total** value, mentioned in the JSON.

In case if the JSON returns 3, 3 tables needs to be populated. Eg: Below format.

[image: Sample table]

Can someone help me with a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to render out *n* "hits" with (I guess) som intensive styling and a lot more info than described, I think you should place it in a small directive :

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('hitTable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      hit: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/hitTable.html'
  }
});
```

`hitTable.html` could look like this (based on sample boxes in the question, add more of the info you want rendered and you must do the styling yourself) :

```
<div>
  <div> {{ hit._source.mdmId }}</div> <!-- sample box #1 -->
    <div> {{ hit._source.firstName }}, {{ hit._source.lastName }}</div> <!-- sample box #2 -->
    <div>
      <span ng-repeat="address in hit._source.partyAdresses"> <!-- n of sample box #3 -->
        {{ address.address1 }}
        {{ address.city }}
        {{ address.state }}
     </span>
  </div>
<div>
```

Once registered in your app and assuming `$scope.data` hold the sample JSON above you can do

```
<div ng-repeat="hit in data.hits.hits">
  <hit-table hit="hit"></hit-table>
</div>
```

In my opinion this is the real power of AngularJS (and its like). With very little effort you can have a rather complex page structure. What you need now is to style each "hit", i.e the content of `hitTable.html`.

NB: I intentionally forget all about "total" here. The important is the content you want to render out, i.e whats within the JSON.